# Should i use encodeURI for username,email and password

Tags: php, jquery

I want to securely send user's three inputs from Jquery/Ajax to PHP and here is my code

```
var username = encodeURI($(".username_inp").val());
        var email = encodeURI($(".email_inp").val());
        var pass = encodeURI($(".pass_inp").val());
        var post = {
            "username":username,
            "email":email,
            "pass":pass,
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/logreg.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {post:JSON.stringify(post)},
            success: function(ans){
                console.log(ans);
            }
        })
```

I wanted to know if my code is right,because as far as i've seen people only use `encodeURI` with URLs

Comment: you don't need to `encodeURI` the fields as they are already in POST body

Comment: @AgamBanga but i can't send `"` without them

Comment: from where `''` is coming into your input

Comment: from value of an input @AgamBanga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6u10t2b/). It is passing `''` to the POST. POST Logs can be found here [Logs](https://requestb.in/1jkr9w11?inspect)

> HTML

```
<input id ="email" />
<input id ="password" />
<input type = "button" id = "btnbtn" value = "Send Ajax">
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#btnbtn').click(function(r) {
r.preventDefault()
var username = $("#email").val();
var email = $("#password").val();
var post = {
  "username":username,
  "email":email
}
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://requestb.in/1jkr9w11',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {post:post},
  success: function(ans){
    console.log(ans);
  }
})

})
```

Comment: I'm talking about double quotes not single

Comment: @BrunoSnickers check i have removed the `JSON.stringify`